# @SpringBootTest uses the wrong application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, integration-testing, h2

I have a spring boot application with a configured MySQL database in application-development.yml in main/resources, which is properly loaded and working when running the application.

I've also created an application-test.yml in test/resources which configures an H2 database, and added h2-database to pom with scope test.

After all that I've created an integration test with `@SpringBootTest` annotation which uses the main `Application.class`. Running these tests however seems to want to initialize the MySQL database, as I see those credentials being used.

I've tried creating a custom `@TestConfiguration` class with a custom `DataSource` instance but it seems to have no effect, even if I set it as the only configuration class (i.e. `@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestConf.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` instead of `@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, TestConf.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`)

It constantly keeps trying to use the configuration defined in main/resources/application-development.yml. What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following line in your test class above `@SpringBootTest`.

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```